# div backgrounds, except header, wont show up?

Tags: html

ive searched around for about a week, but i havent found an answer that really helps me.
im fairly basic at html and the most experience i really have is neopets lol

im making a page for my class at school, and i have three div ids currently active in my page. the header div works fine, but my mainContent and navigation ids seem to ignore the fact that i want the bg colour to be orange. any help would be appreciated!

```
HTML: 
<html><head><title>GUMI MEGPOID | Home</title></head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>GUMI MEGPOID</h1></div>
<div id="navigation">
<p><a href="{text:Link one url}">Home</a>
<a href="{text:Link two url}">Albums</a>
<a href="{text:Link three url}">Lyrics</a>
<a href="{text:Link four url}">Tours</a>
</p></div>
<div id=”mainContent”><p>blah blah blah.<p></div>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {color: #eeee99; font-size: 3 em; text-align: center; }
h2 {color: #eeee99; line-height: 130%; font-size: 1.75 em; font-family: 宋体; }
h3 {color: #eeee99; line-height: 130%; font-size: 1.625 em; }
p {color: #eeee99; line-height: 130%; font-size: .9em; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; }
p1 {color: #eeee99; line-height: 130%; font-size: .75em; }
body { background-color: #eeee99; }
#header { width: 650px; height: 100px; line-height: 100px; background: rgb(238, 119, 34);  margin-bottom: 10%; text-align: center; align: right; }
#mainContent { width: 780px; height: 500px; background: rgb(238, 119, 34);  /* Fallback */ background: rgba(238, 119, 34, .6); text-align: center; }
#navigation { width: 200px; height: 100px; top: auto; margin-left: 160px; position: fixed; margin-top: 10px; -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out; }

#navigation a { font-size: 11px; line-height: 20px; display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px; width: 100px; text-align: center; color: #eeee99; background-color: {color: #ee7722}; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }

#navigation a:hover { color: #eeee99; background-color: {color: #ee7722}; opacity: 0.5; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }</style>
```

Comment: which bg colour to be orange specify `id`

Comment: why don't you just do `background: orange` instead of using these rgbs

Answer (score 4):

The double quotes in this line

```
<div id=”mainContent”><p>blah blah blah.<p></div>
```

should be *straight* (") instead of *curly* (”) quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have the background-color tag wrong on #navigation a.  Try the same as you have in body:

```
  background-color: #ee7722;
```